# popover is not working with jquery select in bootsrap

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display span tag's content when we hover on a tag
 But it has not worked. I checked whether this selector has value  `$(this).find("span").val()` . It worked but when I used it with popover function it has not worked.

```
$(".sidebar-menu > li > a")
   .popover({
      trigger:"hover",
      content:$(this).find("span").val(),
      placement:"right"})
```

But if I pass any span tag then it shows the first span tag's value in popover.

```
 $(".sidebar-menu > li > a")
    .popover({
       trigger:"hover",
       content:$('> span',this).val(),
       placement:"right"})
```

Please help me with this

Comment: What is your `html` ?

Comment: `val()` is for `form inputs`, so you can use `$(this).find("span").text()` for `span`

Comment: I used both html() and  text() but it has not worked

Comment: Open it in Dev Tools. Put a breakpoint on that line, then check to see what `$(this).find('span')` is equal to.

Comment: please add your html which contains sidebar-menu and also let us know which ui library is included in your page